# How to make a custom VScrollbar Associated with a richtextbox?

Tags: c#, .net

i have a `richtextbox` and a `VScrollbar` i set the `ScrollBars` property in the `richtextbox` to `None` and i want my `VScrollbar`to do the same job as the original`ScrollBars`.

Comment: We aren't going to write a scrollbar for you.  Which part is giving you trouble?  Focus on that.  That being said, this looks like a WinForms project.  It's a bit of a waste of resources trying to make something like this work.  WPF allows far more customizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a new `VScrollBar` by setting the `ScrollBars` property to `Vertical`. If this is not what you want, please respond, and I will try my best to  provide a solution.

Comment: No i already know this but i want a separate scrollbar

Comment: why? i don't understand

Comment: I just want it cause it is for my project

Comment: Refer to this Microsoft Document on ScrollBars: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/hscrollbar-and-vscrollbar-controls-overview-windows-forms